# Create table query returns The plugin generated X characters of unexpected output on activation

Tags: wordpress

I'm getting below error while I have more than 70 columns of the table for create table query that I got this error.

> The plugin generated 3351 characters of unexpected output during
>   activation. If you notice “headers already sent” messages, problems
>   with syndication feeds or other issues, try deactivating or removing
>   this plugin.

Here is the code snippet that I have used:

```
[https://pastebin.com/UZ737SH7][1]
```

Here I have some solutions tried
1. I have removed all whitespaces but still not working.
2. It's working fine if I use 10/20 columns for table
3. I didn't tried here for outputting something like echo or print something.

Comment: You are using 3 columns 2 times wish_2_4,kind_2_4,amount_2_4 in your query please remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using 3 columns 2 times wish_2_4,kind_2_4,amount_2_4 in your query please remove it. – Jogi Mehul 27 secs ago

```
public static function create_subgoal_table() {
        global $wpdb;
        $table_name_2 = $wpdb->prefix . 'sub_goals';
        $charset_collate = $wpdb->get_charset_collate();

        $sql_tbl_2 = "CREATE TABLE $table_name_2 (
            id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
            firstname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            lastname VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_1_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_1_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_1_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_2_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            date_2_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_2_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_2_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            kind_2_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_2_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_2_3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            kind_2_3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_2_3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_2_4 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            kind_2_4 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_2_4 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_3_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_3_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_4_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_4_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_4_3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_4_4 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_4_5 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            date_4_6 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_4_7 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_4_8 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_5_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_5_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            date_6_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            what_6_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_6_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            date_6_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            what_6_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_6_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            date_6_3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            what_6_3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_6_3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            years_7_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_7_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_7_3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_8_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_8_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_8_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_8_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_8_3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_8_3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_9_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_9_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_9_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_9_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_10_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_10_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_10_3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            priority_11_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            priority_11_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            priority_11_3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_11_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            year_11_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_11_3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_11_4 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            kind_11_4 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_11_5 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            which_11_5 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_12_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amount_12_1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_12_2 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_12_3 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_12_4 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_12_5 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            which_12_5 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            wish_12_6 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            what_12_6 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            eintrag TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
            UNIQUE KEY id (id)
          ) $charset_collate;";

        require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
        dbDelta( $sql_tbl_2 );
    }
```